# Encrypt and Decrypt small file on android client side (java)

Tags: android, security, encryption, java-security

I generate a small **metadata file** (2KB) from my app which needs to be unreadable if the user browse through file system.  These files will not be transferred elsewhere through my app. 
After prolong research I figured I have to use `Symmetry` encryption.  But I am lost what type of algorithm and how to use key/salt. Efficiency of the algorithm is important because the file is updated on onPause method.

1. Should I declare it in code and use that for all users or should I generate new one for each user. If I go with second option, where do I store the key/salt for later use. Should I obfuscate the code?
   Please advice.
2. Currently I have short listed these two. Are they secure enough for my requirement? How can I improve them?

http://www.codejava.net/coding/file-encryption-and-decryption-simple-example

[String Encryption in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20824708/string-encryption-in-android)

Comment: Use this one: https://github.com/tozny/java-aes-crypto

Comment: Encryption doesn't use salt. Salt is used for hashing only. You only need to worry about the storage of your key.

Comment: thanks, my question is exactly that. Where do I save it for later use and should I generate keys per user basis or should I hard code key in the code so that its global.